# Updating Label when variable changes in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am aiming to make a money counter for the game i am programming.  For example, if I buy something (in the game) I want my money label to update with the new value once this happens.  How would I go about this besides creating a loop that checks every second to see if my variable has changed?  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Tkinter has a way to link widgets and data. You can create an instance of `StringVar`, and assign it to the `textvariable` attribute of a label. Whenever you change the value of the variable, the label will automatically update.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have something like this:

```
def buy_something(amount, thing):
    money -= amount
    ...

def timer():
    ...
    if money != previous_money:
        label.config(text=str(money))
    ...
    root.after(1000, timer)
```

Instead, try something like this:

```
def update_balance(amount):
    money += amount
    label.config(text=str(money))

def buy_something(amount, thing):
    update_balance(-amount) # Change the label when the event occurs!
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ping the money counter with a function whenever an action such as buying or selling something occurs